# redux-form - add fields after initialize but keep dirty values

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I work with a FieldArray.

I'm initializing the form with the initialValues prop from the redux store.

The thing is, after the user changed some form values, he has the option to load more fields from the backend, I want to add the new fields to the form, while keeping the current form state and especially the form "dirty" attribute.

I tried using:

```
keepDirtyOnReinitialize: true,
updateUnregisteredFields: true,
```

But they aren't working.

Comment: can you share you reduxForm initialization ?

Comment: Same case here, did you find a solution?